# Visibility not changing with jquery's .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I want to change the visibility of an element through jquery's `css()` function, but it isn't working. The funny thing is the same syntax works elsewhere on my site, and I can even change the CSS parameter and value *in the same line of code* and it will work. But it does not work for visibility.

My query:

```
$('.promo_container').each(function(promoIndex){

    var $_this = $(this);

    $_this.css({'visibility':'visible'});

    console.log($_this); //This is the correct output ie. the right element

});
```

What's confusing is I use this syntax in another js file and it works. What blows my mind is if I change this line...

```
$_this.css({'visibility':'visible'});
```

...to this...

```
$_this.css({'background':'red'});
```

...it works!! I open my developer console in chrome, and I can see the dynamically set style of the background color. When I switch back to changing the visibility there are no dynamically set styles in my console; it shows `visibility` as `hidden` with nothing overwriting it. But it should be overwritten, shouldn't it?

### EDIT

Keep in mind the issue is not that I cannot see my element, but that the dynamically applied styles show nothing in my developer console. Also, if I uncheck the `visibility:hidden` parameter in my console, then the element shows, so this is the only thing hiding the element.

I have just tried this:

```
$_this.show();
```

It is not working. The element remains hidden. I know I am not targeting the wrong element because, once again, if I change the CSS without changing the selector it works fine; the only issue is when the CSS is setting visibility.

The CSS of the `$_this`:

```
overflow:hidden;
visibility:hidden;
position:relative;
height:100%;
```

The HTML should not be an issue... but this is the markup for my element:

```
<div class="promo_container" data-random="{if $controller->startOn == 1}random{/if}">
    ...
    //That is Smarty syntax inside the element above, 
    it is working fine and should not be affecting anything
</div>
```

### EDIT 2

It was a typo. I had `visibile` instead of `visible`. :D

Comment: Are there any parent elements with `visibility: hidden`?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle to demonstrate the failure?

Comment: Have you tried `display` and `none` / `block`?

Comment: When you log it in the console, has the visibility property of the DOM element changed? @AdrianWragg, that does something entirely different from `visibility`.

Comment: Can you add the existing css as well?

Comment: @Pete failure is such a strong word...

Comment: why don't you use just hide() and show() ?

Comment: @erdimeola Because that is not the same as changing the CSS visibility attribute.

Comment: Wont `visibility:hidden;` cause the element to not even be rendered?

Comment: @tymeJV No. It still takes up space, it just doesn't get painted. This is roughly equivalent to having a transparent element.

Comment: I don't know if this is causing the problem but you are missing the closing ');'

Comment: Would help if you could post your html too.

Comment: It is possible that you have `!important` rules overriding the inline styles applied by `css`.

Comment: @Pete Please see my edit. I don't think a jsfiddle example will benefit because the code 'should' work so I imagine it won't be any different in fiddle.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Please see my edit. Can you explain what you mean by something different?

Comment: I am not sure who gets the "egg in face" award, you for the typo or the rest of us for not not spotting the obvious! On an up note, you will probably never make this error again. :)

Comment: @jefffabiny I didn't say it did something different - that was someone else!

Comment: @MarcAudet The typo was never in the question, so there was no way for anyone to have solved this problem.

Comment: @MarcAudet It is undoubtedly me lol

Comment: @Asad I didn't copy and paste my code from my IDE; I just rewrote it here. Figures I type it right this time... what was happening though was I was using auto complete every time I changed it to visible, but it was wrong in my autocomplete! I must have typed it wrong once and it just saved. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a CSS code overriding your code. can you try

```
$(this).css({'visibility':'visible !important','display':'block',opacity:1});
```

Answer (score 0):

you use: $_this.css({'visibility':'visible'}); only if you have :

**visibility:hidden**  in the css
but if  you are using display:none; in your css

you should use jquery show function

your code will be:

```
$('.promo_container').each(function(promoIndex){

    var $_this = $(this);

    $_this.show();

    console.log($_this); //This is the correct output ie. the right element

}
```

Comment: Please see my edit. `.show()` is not working for me either. The computed styles in my console show that `display` is set to block.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code out independently and the following seems to work fine:

```
$('.promo_container').each(function(promoIndex){
    alert(promoIndex);
    var $_this = $(this);
    $_this.css({'visibility' : 'visible' });
})
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/9mgVt/

Something else is going on...

Comment: Sorry, my fault, that was a typo. I have fixed my question, but this is not the issue.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways an elements can be hidden.

For example, it can have a `display: none` CSS property, or the `hidden="hidden"` HTML attribute.

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/show/) has a method `.show()` to resolve all of these cases.

Comment: The `display` attribute behaves very differently from the `visibility` attribute.

Comment: opacity would be better than display in this case